# Limit and offset do not work for pagination in Codeigniter3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use CI3 and want to use pagination for my website. I used this tutorial for pagination https://www.codexworld.com/ajax-pagination-in-codeigniter-framework/ and it works somehow. I have 12 rows in the database and set the limit to 1, however, it shows that there are 12 pages (which is true) but fetches all 12 rows from the database as in the image (Look at scroll and number of pages):

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmMG7.jpg)

Here is my controller:

```
function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->library('Ajax_pagination');
            $this->perPage = 1;
        }


        public function index(){

            //total rows count
            $totalRec = count($this->collections_model->get_collections());
            $limit = $this->perPage;

            //pagination configuration
            $config['target']      = '#ajpag';
            $config['base_url']    = base_url().'collections/ajaxPaginationData';
            $config['total_rows']  = $totalRec;
            $config['per_page']    = $this->perPage;
            $this->ajax_pagination->initialize($config);

            //get the posts data

            $data['title'] = 'Collections';
            $data['collections'] = $this->collections_model->get_collections(FALSE, $limit);

            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('pages/index', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }

        function ajaxPaginationData(){
            $page = $this->input->post('page');
            if(!$page){
                $offset = 0;
            }else{
                $offset = $page;
            }

            //total rows count
            $totalRec = count($this->collections_model->get_collections());
            $limit = $this->perPage;

            //pagination configuration
            $config['target']      = '#ajpag';
            $config['base_url']    = base_url().'collections/ajaxPaginationData';
            $config['total_rows']  = $totalRec;
            $config['per_page']    = $this->perPage;
            $this->ajax_pagination->initialize($config);

            //get the posts data
            $data['collections'] = $this->collections_model->get_collections(false, $limit, $offset);

            //load the view
            $this->load->view('collections/ajax-pagination-data', $data, false);
        }
```

And here is my model:

```
public function get_collections($id = FALSE, $limit = FALSE, $offset = FALSE) {
        if ($id === FALSE) {
            $query = $this->db->get('collections');
            $this->db->order_by('id','desc');

            if($limit && $offset){
                $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
            }elseif(!$offset && $limit){
                $this->db->limit($limit);
            }

            return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('collections', array('id' => $id));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
```

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `get` after apply the limit, etc.

```
public function get_collections($id = FALSE, $limit = FALSE, $offset = FALSE) {
    if ($id === FALSE) {
        $this->db->order_by('id','desc');

        if($limit && $offset){
            $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
        }elseif(!$offset && $limit){
            $this->db->limit($limit);
        }

        $query = $this->db->get('collections'); //call get here
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('collections', array('id' => $id));
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

Comment: Oh, how I forgot that? :D